# MobileFirst BlueMix container port

Tags: containers, ibm-cloud, ibm-mobilefirst

How can I change the default port (9080) for MobileFirst container? I've specified custom ports during the creation of a container but MF defaults to 9080. Many organizations block these ports, making evaluation very difficult. Does anyone know any good solution to this? Thanks!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The ports for the evaluation (ibm-mobilefirst-starter) container are fixed - 80, 9080. These cannot be changed / modified.